# Divisibility Of Positve Integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, contest-math

Suppose a,b and c are three positive integers which satisfy the condition that ($a$<sup>2</sup>+$b$<sup>2</sup>+$c$<sup>2</sup>) is divisible by $(a+b+c)$.

Prove that there exists infinitely many positive integers $n$  for which ($a$<sup>n</sup>+$b$<sup>n</sup>+$c$<sup>n</sup>) is also divisible by$(a+b+c)$.

Comment: Please show some of what you have tried.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: This is very close to an exercise from a South American olympiad last year. I do not see a reason to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $(a^{2^n}+b^{2^n}+c^{2^n})$ is divisible by $(a+b+c)$ for each $n\geq 0$.

The proof is by induction on $n$. The base cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are given to us; suppose that it is true for $n$ and $n-1$.  Then $$2(a^{2^{n-1}}b^{2^{n-1}}+a^{2^{n-1}}c^{2^{n-1}}+b^{2^{n-1}}c^{2^{n-1}}) = (a^{2^{n-1}}+b^{2^{n-1}}+c^{2^{n-1}})^2 - (a^{2^n}+b^{2^n}+c^{2^n})$$ is also divisible by $(a+b+c)$.

We then have $$(a^{2^{n+1}}+b^{2^{n+1}} + c^{2^{n+1}}) = (a^{2^n}+b^{2^n}+c^{2^n})^2 - 2(a^{2^{n-1}}b^{2^{n-1}}+a^{2^{n-1}}c^{2^{n-1}}+b^{2^{n-1}}c^{2^{n-1}})^2 + 4(a^{2^{n-1}}+b^{2^{n-1}}+c^{2^{n-1}})(a^{2^{n-1}}b^{2^{n-1}}c^{2^{n-1}}),$$
and each term on the right hand side is divisible by $(a+b+c)$ by the above and the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  think about $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$